# How to create abaqus model using script according to joints directly

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm working on a transformer which can transform the sap2000 model to Abaqus model, and this can finish the work like modeling, add boundary, add load and so on.

There are beam elements and shell elements in my model.

1.At first, I read the .s2k file, and I use **myPart.Element(...)** function to create beam element or shell element.(myPart = mdb.models['Model-1'].Part(name='structure')). So my model consists of elements only.

this is my modeling result, you can see I only have elements in the model

[image]

2.And in this way, I can calculate normal structures, but my question is: If the structure has to prestress, I want to add minus temperature to the specified frame to simulate prestressing. But as step 1 said, the model only has elements, and PredefinedFiled in Load Module **can't** add temperature on elements......

3.So my idea now is to create faces and lines according to the joints they belong(i.e. **not** create elements directly), but I can't find functions in [abaqus scripting reference guide](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm)......

So can anyone help? **Thanks, all!!**

Comment: likely you can do what you need directly in the inp.

Comment: Reviewing this again, predefined temperature is defined on nodes, and this should not be an issue for your element based model, you just need to define the appropriate node sets.